# Recursive Python Methods

Tags: python, recursion

I am writing a program to solve a type of square puzzle, which by brute force tries every possible combination of pieces until it finds something that works.

The board  looks like this

1   -  2  - 3

4  -   5  -  6

7  -  8   -  9

I began with a bunch of nested for loops,

```
 for a in range(1,10):
     #create piece
     #than test it
     if checkPiece(pieceNumber):
          for b in range (1,10):
```

...and so on, for nine times.

Then I realized that the same thing could be accomplished with two recursive functions, which would try a piece than if correct call a second function which would then reference the first function with success!

```
def Solve():
    global level;
    global AvailableNumbers;
    if level == 10:
        Solved();
    for i in AvailableNumbers:
        print "We are %d far into level %d with fct. ONE" %(i,level);
        clearList(level);
        AvailableNumbers.remove(i)
        spot[level] = pieces[i];
        result = checkPiece(level)
        print result
        if result == True:
            level += 1
            Solve2();
        else:
            AvailableNumbers.append(i);
            spot[level] = [];
```

The second function is the same as the first (except it calls the first).

The problem with this code is that it keeps ending prematurely, and Solved() is never called.

I suspect that when a method is called it may override any previous activity to that method (thus ending my recursive dreams), but can't be sure if there are other mistakes in my code.

Is there any way to recursively call for loops inside of for loops,

(not for{}for{}for{} but for{for{for{for{}}}})

without having to write it all out?

Thanks for reading all of this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: don't modify a list while iterating over it

Comment: [link] (http://www.b-dazzle.com/scramble.asp) -This is the type of puzzle. They sure can be frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like the following:

```
def Solve(level, available_numbers):
  if level == 10:
    return spot
  for i in available_numbers:
    print "We are %d far into level %d with fct. ONE" %(i,level)
    clearList(level)
    # Note you are not removing i from available_numbers yet
    spot[level] = pieces[i]
    result = checkPiece(level)
    print result
    if result == True:
      available_number = available_number.remove(i)
      Solve(level + 1, available_number)  # tail recursion!

    # note no need for your else statement. We haven't removed i from our list yet,
    # and we can just overwrite spot[level] on the next pass.
```

I cannot test this without the rest of the code, but the idea is basically to call recursive iterations of your `Solve` function with a decreasing number pool until you have every number in a spot that works. I assume that `spot` is your solution vector, so at the very end, we return `spot` which gets passed back up the chain to the top and output. If `spot` is not globally accessible, you could add it as another input to your function and pass it down the line as you make your recursive calls.

If you are interested in really diving into recursion, check out the stellar [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) course from MIT. The full book is available at that link for free. I have been working through it in [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/), which I also do not mind recommending.

**Edit:** from our discussion in the comments, it sounds like each level of recursion needs to check if the previous level returned a valid solution or just stopped without finding a solution, and then either pass the valid solution up or continue on to the next iteration of its `for` loop accordingly. Maybe something like this?

```
def Solve(level, nums, spot):
  if level = 10:  # maybe check if nums = [] for an arbitrary number of levels?
    return (spot, True)  # pass back solution and Boolean saying it's solved
  for i in nums:
    # place your next piece
    result = checkPiece(level)
    if result:  # no need for the "== True" bit
      nums = nums.remove(i)
      spot, solved = Solve(level + 1, nums, spot)  # recursive call
      if solved:  # valid solution reached?
        return (spot, solved)  # pass new solution up the chain
      # else continue to the next iteration of the for loop
  return (spot, False)  # reach this if no valid solution is found at this level
```

The key change is that now we pass our updated solution vector back up the chain explicitly, in addition to passing a Boolean that tells us whether a valid solution has been reached. You could also check whether the solution is valid at every level, but that seems less efficient. If our `for` loop at any level gets exhausted, we return `solved = False`, which bumps us up to the next iteration of the next-higher level's `for` loop. Let me know if this gets you where you need to go.

Comment: This works better than my previous function, however it ends abruptly at 8 (of 9). It seems that all of the pieces are fit in except the last one, and then when the last one doesn't work the whole thing abruptly stops.

Comment: Also, it seems that `available_number.remove(i) ` doesn't return anything. I replaced it with    `available_numbers.remove(i)
      Solve(level + 1,available_numbers ) `

Comment: Hmm...I will think about that. I'm pretty sure we are on the right track, but I probably have some error in there somewhere.

Comment: Also I added your correction to the recursive call. Good call!

Comment: OK, I think the problem that you are having now is different from your recursion problem. Without knowing the specifics of your "game", I don't think that I can answer it. My understanding is that you are checking for a fit for one piece at a time, and my hunch is that there are some solution vectors where piece 1, 2, 3, ... fits but then you get to piece 8 or 9 and there is no longer any possible fit. Trying to solve this sort of problem sequentially may run into this issue. Without knowing more about it I can't be sure, but did this help with your recursion question?

Comment: You're right. This is the type of puzzle where all but one piece can be in place, and the last piece doesn't fit. You then have to rearrange all of the other pieces until it does. With nested for loops, you can have a system where every sixth piece is tried until one fits, then the seventh pieces are tried, and crucially, if none fit it will go right back to the last tried solution for the previous piece, and if that fails, than it will go to the piece before that. I'm not sure if memory like that is possible in functions that are being re-called as they run.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I will definitely check out those resources.

Comment: I made some edits to my answer that I think might address some of these issues. I edited it around when the servers went down today, so not sure if the notification went through...

Comment: This seems to work! Thanks for all your help here, I have a much better understanding of recursion now.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it.